# Change the default mode used when opening a new buffer

Tags: buffers, major-mode

For example, we can open a new buffer with `C-x b <new-buffer-name>`, and by default, this new buffer opens in `fundamental-mode`, which is not very useful to me. I would like to change this to open all new buffers in `org-mode`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to customize the `major-mode` variable [(see also the emacs manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html). `C-h v`:

> Symbol for current buffer's major mode.
>
> The default value (normally `fundamental-mode') affects new buffers.
>    A value of nil means to use the current buffer's major mode, provided
>    it is not marked as "special".

You can do this with `M-x customize-variable major-mode` or with something like `(setq-default major-mode 'org-mode)` somewhere in your init file.

See also `initial-major-mode` for the `*scratch*` buffer.

Comment: In my testing(Emacs 28.2), only the "M-x customize-variable major-mode" works, "(setq-default major-mode 'org-mode)" did not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `init.el` one string:

```
(setq initial-major-mode (quote <major mode name>))
```

For example, I use `markdown-mode` as primary mode on my job:

```
(setq initial-major-mode (quote markdown-mode))
```