# New buffers of the same name don't inherit default major mode?

Tags: major-mode

I'm using the following to create a new buffer "untitled" with the keyboard map `C-n`. This works fine for a new buffer but additional buffers of the same name where `<num>` gets applied seem to inherit the Fundamental major mode rather than Text. Why is this?

```
(setq major-mode 'text-mode)

(defun new-buffer-by-name (arg)
   "Creates a new buffer by name"
   (generate-new-buffer arg)
   (set-buffer-major-mode (get-buffer arg))
   (switch-to-buffer arg))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-n")
   (lambda () (interactive)
      (new-buffer-by-name "untitled")))
```

Comment: Looks very releated to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14013/change-the-default-mode-used-when-opening-a-new-buffer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `C-h v major-mode`, you'll see:

> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

To set the default value (and not only a buffer-local value), use `(setq-default major-mode 'text-mode)` instead.

Moreover, you create a new buffer with `generate-new-buffer` but don't actually run `set-buffer-major-mode` on it.

Lastly, I suggest to make `new-buffer-by-name` itself an interactive function.

The code then becomes :

```el
(setq-default major-mode 'text-mode)

(defun new-buffer-by-name (bufname)
  "Creates a new buffer by name"
  (interactive (list "untitled"))
  (let ((newbuf (generate-new-buffer bufname)))
    (set-buffer-major-mode newbuf)
    (switch-to-buffer newbuf)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-n") #'new-buffer-by-name)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when creating additional buffers of the same where <num> is appended.

Comment: @Zhro I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Of course.. I'm setting the major mode for "untitled" instead of the new buffer! D: